# How To Receive Parse Push Notification JSON Data Through Custom BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am not seeing this in the documentation. Previously in 1.3.9 there was data passed via the extras bundle of an intent object, after upgrading to 1.9.1 we are seeing that bundle returned as null. How are we supposed to fetch the json data sent with a push notificatio via a custom broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In past versions of Parse SDK you would subclass a normal BroadcastReceiver and be able to get the JSON payload from the intent extras just fine. In newer versions of the SDK you need to subclass ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and implement 'protected onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent)' where you had previously implemented 'void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)' in order to access the JSON payload.